# PyQt6 Mouse Hover event over QPushButtons in a gridlayout

Tags: python, pyqt6, eventfilter

I'm trying to connect Mouse Hover Event and QPushButtons. I want to change CheckStatus on the next when I hover over it after I pressed on one of the button.

[image]

I was able to connect this event with the buttons. But I can't understand how to connect it with press button event.

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    uic.loadUi("my_file.ui", self)

    self.gridLayout.installEventFilter(self)

    for button in self.gridLayoutWidget.findChildren(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton):
        button.clicked.connect(self.rangeButtonClicked)
        button.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_Hover)
        button.installEventFilter(self)

    self.gridLayout.installEventFilter(self)

def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if event.type() == QEvent.Type.HoverEnter:
        sender = obj
        sender.nextCheckState()

    return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Required actions:

1. I press the button
2. I move the mouse along the rest of the buttons
3. The pressed button and those over which the mouse hover - change the status

Comment: Supposing that `self.gridLayout` is a layout, it won't work, as layout managers are not widgets, they don't get mouse events.

Comment: Yap, I got it, thx. I've changed my task. A little bit.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. Maybe you want to have a "drag" effect, so that you press the mouse button (but not release it) and toggle any other button when you pass over them with the mouse, until the mouse button is released?

Comment: Yes, I want this effect. Now I have a temporary solution. Hover event activates when checkbox is checked.

Comment: That might not work, especially if you want to do that while dragging the mouse and the mouse button is pressed. It might also be important to know if you also need to connect the buttons to their `toggled`, assuming those are all checkable buttons. Please [edit] your question and try to be *as clear as you can* in explaining what is the expected result, including alternate cases/behavior.